# What is this icon for in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I found this link for `TFS` Icons but what I was looking for was not there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245455.aspx

I need to create what ever it is next to the **"Framework"** one...The ones below it are `folder` but what should I create to have the same icon as the one next to Framework?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a branch, put simply a stand-alone copy of another folder. Those folders can get synchronized with each other by merging changes from one branch to another. Right click on the source folder you would like to branch, and select `Branching and Merging` > `Branch ...` in the context menu. The destination path will be created and linked with the source folder. After checking-in, you can merge new change-sets from one branch to another by using the context menu again (`Merge...`).

See also: [Defining Your Branching and Merging Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx) and [TFS Branching and Merging Guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598921.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This icon next to Framework is for a branch and the other icons are Folders. The link provided here gives you more details on this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2009/09/09/vsts-2010-tfs-branches-and-folders.aspx

This icon was introduced in TFS 2010.